# Cast byte array to int

Tags: c, casting, data-conversion

I have an array of four `bytes` and want to cast it to an `int`. The following code works just fine for that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint8_t array[4] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xC0, 0xDE};
    uint32_t myint;
    myint  = (uint32_t)(array[0]) << 24;
    myint |= (uint32_t)(array[1]) << 16;
    myint |= (uint32_t)(array[2]) << 8;
    myint |= (uint32_t)(array[3]);

    printf("0x%x\n",myint);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is as expected:

```
$./test
0xdeadc0de
```

Now I want to do this in a one-liner like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint8_t array[4] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xC0, 0xDE};
    uint32_t myint = (uint32_t)(array[0]) << 24 || (uint32_t)(array[1]) << 16 || (uint32_t)(array[2]) << 8 || (uint32_t)(array[3]);

    printf("0x%x\n",myint);
    return 0;
}
```

But this results in:

```
$./test
0x1
```

Why does my program behave like this?

Comment: Voting to close this as simple typo, doubt this thread is of any interest to anyone any longer, including the OP after realizing the typo.

Comment: upvote for using portable code instead of undefined aliasing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are mixing up the operators for the logical *or* (`||`) and the bit wise *or* (`|`).

Do

```
uint32_t myint = (uint32_t)(array[0]) << 24 
  | (uint32_t)(array[1]) << 16
  | (uint32_t)(array[2]) << 8 
  | (uint32_t)(array[3]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Logical OR `||` is different from bitwise OR `|`

So in your 2nd snippet you use `||` use `|`